# How can I have a fixed width div inside of a variable width div without overflow?

Tags: css

I have a "wrapper" div, of let's say a width of 80%, around a div where I want to limit the width (a form for example) to 300px. When the controls are set to "fill" the width the controls overlap the "wrapper" div. I obviously find this ugly. I know I can set the overflow attribute to just add scrollbars, but what I'd really like to do is prevent the "wrapper" div from narrowing smaller than its content.

Answer (score 0):

Give the wrapper a min-width of 300px along after the width 80%

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set a min-width on your wrapper container. Here is a simple example:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 300px; /*This should be at least as wide as your form, wider if you need extra room */
    position: relative;
}

form {
    width: 300px;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've set up a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/MhxVz/

Comment: Is this "really" how designers are doing this in the wild? Seems really odd that I'd have to plan a style template around what my content may or may not be. Why is it that the parent needs to be given a hint as to the size of its contents anyway?

Comment: The parent needs to be given a hint as to the size of the contents since your parent has a variable width, whereas your form is a fixed width. This is more necessary when you're considering how things will scale for mobile, for example. If that's not your situation, perhaps you could expand a bit more. You don't have to plan your template around this, it's just giving the parent a min-width.